# Iterative Expectation of a Random Sequence a fucntion of Continuous Uniform Random Variable (Solved)

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, random-variables, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

Problem: Let $X$ be uniformly distributed in the unit interval $[0,1]$, let
\begin{equation*}
   Y_n=
     \begin{cases}
       0, & \text{if}\:X \geq \dfrac{1}{n} \\ \\
       n, & \text{if}\:X < \dfrac{1}{n}
     \end{cases}
 \end{equation*}

a) Show the sequence $Y_n$ converges to $0$.

b) Prove $E[Y_n]=\dfrac{1}{2}$

$\underline{\text{My Attempt}}$

a) Convergence in probability concept can be used. But using the intution since $X \sim \text{Uni}[0,1]$ therefore

$P(X<\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n}$ and $P(X \geq \frac{1}{n})=1-\frac{1}{n}$

Hence as $n \to \infty$

$P(Y_n = 0) = 1$ and $P(Y_n = n) = 0$

Therefor $Y_n$ converges to $0$.

b)
\begin{align*}
  E[Y_n] &= E[E[Y_n|X]] \\
  &=P(X<\frac{1}{n})E[Y_n|X<\frac{1}{n}]+P(X\geq\frac{1}{n})\underbrace{E[Y_n|X\geq\frac{1}{n}]}_{0}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}nP(Y_n|X<\frac{1}{n})+0\\
&=\frac{1}{n}n\dfrac{P(\{Y_n=n\} \cap \{X<\frac{1}{n}\})}{P(X<\frac{1}{n})}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}n\dfrac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}n\cdot 1\\
&=1
\end{align*}

I am thankful to the author of the book, they have confirmed that it was a mistake in the book so the summation is not required since it is a sequence therefore the answer is $1$ as one of the person comment (Thank you
Dominik Kutek).

Comment: I don't understand what's your reasoning with that summation in b). Note that $Y_n$ takes only values $n$ and $0$, hence $\mathbb E[Y_n] = 0 \cdot \mathbb P(Y_n = 0) + n \cdot \mathbb P(Y_n = n) = n \cdot \mathbb P(Y_n = n) = n \mathbb P(X < \frac{1}{n}) = n \cdot \frac{1}{n} = 1$ (not $\frac{1}{2}$).  As for a), it's easier to write $Y_n = n 1_{\{X < \frac{1}{n}\}}$ and note that for fixed $\omega$,  $1_{\{X(\omega) < \frac{1}{n}\}}$ is $0$ (at least for a.e $\omega$) for $n$ large enough (depending on $\omega$) which shows that $Y_n \to 0$ almost surely.

Comment: It is a question from the book "Introduction To Probability" 2nd Edition by by Dimitri P. Bertsekas, John N. Tsitsiklis Problem 7-35. In its solution they have written $E[Y_n] = P(X<\frac{1}{n})E[Y_n|X<\frac{1}{n}] = \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{n}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$, for all $n$. So in order to get the result I try to use definitions.

Comment: $Y_n$ is a sequence. I generated first twenty values of the sequence in matlab using the following code                                                                                                        
% Set the seed for reproducibility
rng(42);

% Number of values to generate
num_values = 20;

% Generate and print the first 20 values of the sequence
for n = 1:num_values
    X = rand(); % Generate a random number in the interval [0, 1]
    if X >= 1/n
        Y_n = 0;
    else
        Y_n = n;
    end
    fprintf('Y_%d = %d\n', n, Y_n);
end